# When I run cucumber with testng, using mvn command line, how do I display the allure report

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, allure, cucumber-java

When I try to run the cucumber-testng by using ***mvn clean test*** the result says, 1test run, how do I generate allure report displaying the Scenarios and Steps

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**: you need to enable and configure surefire plugin for TestNG.

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Add dependency to your pom as well:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And finally add allure maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
</plugin>
```

**Secondly**: you need to let your tests know where you allure results directory is (in my sxample - allure-results directory in root directory). You can achieve that by adding `allure.properties` file in your resources folder with value: `allure.results.directory=target/allure-results`.
After that you can issue `mvn allure:serve` after your tests completed.